# "Hyperbolic rigidity of higher rank lattices" by Thomas Haettel

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\MCG{MCG}\DeclareMathOperator\CC{C}$In the article "Hyperbolic rigidity of higher rank lattices", Thomas Haettel has proved the following theorem: Let $\Gamma$ be a lattice in (a product) of higher rank almost simple connected algebraic groups with finite centers over a local field and $S_{g,p}$ be a closed surface of genus $g$ with $p$ punctures. Then any morphism $\Gamma$ to $\MCG(S_{g,p})$ has a finite image, where MCG is the abbreviation for Mapping Class Group. The article is available [here on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.02004).

On page 18, he has proved the above-mentioned theorem. In the proof (6th line), he has mentioned the following statement: "According to [Iva92], any subgroup of $\MCG(S)$ having an elementary action on $\CC(S)$ is either virtually cyclic or reducible". He has mentioned the whole book for reference. Can somebody tell which theorem of [Iva92] is he using? or can somebody give a proof of the statement ``any subgroup of $\MCG(S)$ having an elementary action on $\CC(S)$ is either virtually cyclic or reducible’'?

In the same proof (9th line), he has made the following statement: ``Observe that the stabilizer of $c$ in $\MCG(S)$ is a (product of) mapping class groups of surfaces of smaller complexities’’. How can one prove this statement?

[Iva92] N. V. Ivanov Subgroups of Teichmüller modular groups. Transl. Math. Monog., 115. AMS, 1992.

Comment: These kinds of statements (certainly the second one) are proved in Farb and Margalit's "Primer on Mapping Class Groups". It sounds like you haven't worked much with mapping class groups before -- it might beneficial to read that book (or, at least, several chapters) before attempting to understand Haettel's paper.